# How do I strip litz wire?

Tags: wire, tools, insulation, litz-wire

I bought a choke made of litz wire. The wire is enameled all the way to the ends. How does one go about stripping this wire?

Comment: Duplicates here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53028/how-to-remove-enamel-from-wire?rq=1
and here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8203/whats-the-best-cheap-way-of-stripping-enamel-off-of-magnet-wire?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fire.**

You can burn off a good bit of the enamel at the ends with fire. You can also [use various chemicals](http://www.litz-wire.com/dipstripop.php) to strip the enamel.

If the ultimate purpose is to tin the wire, use a solder pot, it's the [recommended method](http://www.newenglandwire.com/~/media/Files/Litz%20Wire%20Termination%20guide%204th%20Edition.pdf).

Comment: Just dont breathe the fumes while melting it.

Comment: Under the "various chemicals" section, I just had good luck with acetone.