# Do the very thin wires of headphones have a name?

Tags: wire

Do the very thin wires of headphones have a name?
by headphone wires I mean the usually green, red and twisted ground cables, about 0.1 mm thick.

Comment: 0.1 could use some units. I'm not sure if there's a universal headphone wire standard, and if there's not, that thickness would help identify the gauge you're looking at. Also, what's your goal? To buy more of the same wire?

Comment: The following article refers to "acrylic-insulated" wires where each line has several individually-insulated wires, all twisted together: http://www.alexwhittemore.com/soldering-the-thinnest-wires-ever-conceived-headphone-modding/ — but that isn't really giving the wires a unique name.

Comment: Transformer wire? Enamelled copper wire?

Comment: What is "0,1" thick? This is an English language site, which dictates use of the period (.) as a decimal mark. Also you should provide the unit (millimeters? inches?).

Comment: @JYelton  It's mm, of course.  0.1 inch [or 2.54mm in free countries] would be a thick wire [about 10 AWG].  In the SI system of units either point or comma can be used as a decimal marker.

Comment: I don't think any unit should be assumed. As for the decimal, see: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/1451/2028

Comment: Often headphones use "tinsel wire", because it's very flexible and doesn't tend to fatigue from flexing.  The stuff, however, is a b***h to terminate -- must be crimped, not soldered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's referred to as various things - magnet, enamel or litz wire IME.

[image]

References/examples for the names:

[Litz](http://www.doublehelixcables.com/store/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1&products_id=105&zenid=khdqgr9ah6sjk30604iltred20)
[Litz 2](http://www.moon-audio.com/diy-audio-parts/audio-wire/cardas-tonearm-4x33-wire-bulk.html#)
[Litz 3](http://www.estron.dk/english/unique-products-for-iems-and-earphones/cpt,-esw,-xt-esw-litz-and-solid-wires.aspx)
[Discussion of name](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=674898)
[SE question with comments on headphone wire](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7489/how-do-you-remove-insulation-from-headphone-wires)

Comment: [Litz wire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire) is, I believe, a bit different from magnet wire, in that it *consists of many thin wire strands, individually insulated and twisted or woven together, following one of several carefully prescribed patterns*. Magnet wire is more typically a single core wire with thin acrylic / enamel / polymer film insulation.

Comment: @Anindo - yes I agree, personally I would call it something like multi-strand magnet/enamel wire. I was just listing what I had heard folk refer to headphone wire as.

Comment: @Anindo - I added some links with examples/discussion on the subject.

Comment: thanks!
Sorry for the missing unit and decimal period -1 for me.