# What type of wire is that? How can I solder two ends together?

Tags: soldering, wiring

I need to reconnect two parts that I had to separate. The wires look unusual and I’m unsure how to solder the two ends together. They are stranded but don’t have a plastic coating. The middle looks like a white fiber.

The solder wire doesn’t attach well to them.

[image]

Comment: You left out the fact that those are headphone wires (I assume I have never seen it used anywhere else). That's very important info. That's because headphone conductors are coated similar to magnet wire. However, unlike magnet wire you can't scrape off the coating because the strands are too thin. Not much you can do. If it is actually the same type of insulation as magnet wire, heating an aspirin with a soldering iron will produce an acid that strips it but it makes toxic fumes.

Comment: The white fiber is nylon or similar, used to give the contraption a measure of strength.  The "wires" are made of multiple strands, each strand is ALSO nylon, cotton (or similar) wound with a SUPER tiny thread of copper.. like gauge 60 stuff, thinner than hair.   Presumably this gives a build with minimal copper usage.  GET A GOOD MAGNIFICATION DEVICE and the construction will become very obvious to you.   Insofar as how to connect to it, I believe its usually done with crimps, not soldering.  But I could be wrong about that, I haven't actually investigated.

Comment: A conductive epoxy might work as well

Comment: Those are earphone wires.  The individual strands are insulated with lacquer (paint.) It can be soldered, but it is a bit tricky.  [This question and answer show how.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565015/what-are-those-weird-wires-in-the-audio-cables)

Comment: Thanks all. I encountered those on a wireless charger, not headphones but they seem to be the same wires. I’ll update the post if I can make something work.

Comment: Consider: If those wires really were not insulated ("don’t have a plastic coating"), then bundling them together in the same cable would make them short out and not deliver any power form the charger to the device being charged. So since presumably the charger did once work - the wires therefor *must* be insulated. Now consider that one of them is *blue* - is that a "natural" color for a copper wire? No it isn't. So again we can deduce that there is *something* insulating those wires from each other. That something is an enamel coating, and you cannot solder to the wires without removing it.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know exactly what the insulating material is but I’ve come across this type of wire before; it’s very difficult to work with.  Perhaps try scraping the insulation off, or burn it with a flame.  Then try to tin the copper at normal so soldering temperature.