# Need vendor and type of wire used in headphones

Tags: identification, wiring, wire

I have Soundcore Vortex A3031 folding Bluetooth headphones. The issue with the headphones is that the left speaker no longer works.

I have troubleshot the headphones and there is a break in the wiring harness. I have also contacted tech support at Soundcore, but they don't sell the harness and basically started selling me a newer version of the headset. No, thanks.

I have looked for this type of wire online to no avail. I have no idea what it's called or where I can purchase this type of wire. These wires are small, flexible, and have colored insulation. I have included a picture of the wires.

I'm hoping someone can share the information I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are those weird wires in the audio cables?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/565015/what-are-those-weird-wires-in-the-audio-cables)

Comment: The linked question and answer contain hints to soldering headset wires.

Answer (score 1):

That is a special type of wire.  Each colored wire is made of individual copper strands that are insulated with lacquer or enamel.  The strands are wrapped around a string.

Where to buy things is off topic, but you might already have some in your home.

The typical wired headset used with Android phones is usually made with such wire.  I've made gadgets from such headsets, and usually found that kind of wire in them.

That said, I've found it by searching for "stranded enamelled copper wire."  The rolls are rather large and expensive.  It'll probably be cheaper to buy an Android headset and cut it apart than to buy even just one roll of wire.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: see GodJihyo's answer above.  Before you go ordering wire, I would make sure that you can correctly identify the break, access it without permanently destroying the headphones, and fix it with the tools you have on hand or at least don't mind buying.

Comment: That's not simple hookup wire.  Each wire is made of individual strands insulated with lacquer.  They are typically used in headsets.

Comment: @jre - insulated strands for skin effect? The skin depth at 20 kHz is about the dia of 26 AWG.

Comment: It sounds like more for flexibility than skin effect ala Litz wire.  Haven't heard of tinsel wire before, which it sounds like this is.

Comment: @Vir:  This is not "tinsel" wire.

Comment: @Mattman944:  It is for flexibility, though some hifi nuts will probably claim all kinds of magical effects (good and bad) for it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tinsel wire.

Tinsel wire is a thin metallic foil wrapped around a fiber core. It is very flexible but has low current carrying capability and generally requires crimped connectors as it's difficult to solder. It's used a lot in things like headphones, coiled microphone cables, and old telephone handsets where flexibility is the most important requirement.

Edit: Per JRE, similar to tinsel but with stranded enameled wires instead of a foil. The idea is the same, the wires are thin enough to be flexible while the fiber core gives it strength.

Comment: It's not tinsel.  You can zoom in on the pictures and see the strands.  It's enamelled copper wire.

Comment: Okay, I hadn't seen this kind before. Similar to tinsel but with thin enamel wire instead of foil.